# Variable Scope Question PHP

Tags: php, scope

In the following code the variable does not seem to be getting set. Seems simple enough but for some reason this is vexing me.

```
function teasertext($string){
    $tstring = "";
    if (strlen($string)>9){
        $tstring .= substr($string,0,9) . "....";
    }
    else
    {
        $tstring .= $string;
    }
}
print $tstring;
return $tstring;
```

Comment: Rule #1, always indent consistently.  It will show you why some things don't work (in your case, the `print` and `return` statements are outside of the function block)...

Answer (score 2):

```
print $tstring;
return $tstring;
```

is outside of the function block.

```
function teasertext($string){
    $tstring = "";
    if (strlen($string)>9){
        $tstring .= substr($string,0,9) . "....";
    }
    else
    {
        $tstring .= $string;
    }
    print $tstring;
    return $tstring;
}
```

Should return $tstring properly.

Answer (score -1):

I placed the variables outside of the function. Silly mistake.